# shinydashboard: Load tabItems at top of page when menuItem clicked

Tags: javascript, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I am developing a shiny app with multiple tabs (about 10), each of which contains long content (scrolling within each tab is necessary). When a user scrolls down the page on one tab, and then selects another tab from the sidebar menu, the new tab loads in the same scroll position in the mainpanel as the prior tab. I would like the mainpanel (dashboard body) to return to the top of the page every time a tabItem is clicked on the sidebar menu.

I have tried a few solutions using shinyjs, but I am a complete novice when it comes to javascript. I found the following code in another question here that I've tried to implement without success, using the div name of my sidebar header (tabs):

```
tags$script(" $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#tabs a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]').bind('click', function (e) {
            $(document).load().scrollTop(0);
            });

            });")
```

The above code will only run in the sidemenu section of the app. Placing it in either the dashboardPagePlus() code or the dashboardBody() sections throws and error due to unexpected class issues within the js code. I've also tried to use code for one specific tab in the div reference to see if I can get just one tab to work, to no avail (using "#shiny-tab-subtab1" instead of "tabs").

Below is a working example. I've placed some extra tall plots in each tab so that I can test the scrolling behavior as I try solutions. I am pretty sure this requires a javascript solution. Any help you can provide would be much appreciated!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(tidyverse)
library(datasets)
library(shinyjs)

data <- data.frame(x=c(0,1,2,3,4), y = c(0,1,2,3,4))

ui <- 
  dashboardPagePlus(
skin = "green",
header = dashboardHeaderPlus(disable = FALSE,
                             title = "ScrolltoTop Testing"
),


dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    style = "position:relative;",
    id = "tabs",
    menuItem("FirstTab", 
             menuItem("Test 1", tabName = "subtab1"),
             menuItem("Test 2",tabName = "subtab2")
             ),
    menuItem("SecondTab", 
             menuItem("Test 3", tabName = "subtab3"),
             menuItem("Test 4",tabName = "subtab4")
             )
  )),


dashboardBody(
  position = "fixed-top",
  #prevent sidebar scrolling
  tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "subtab1",
      fluidRow(column(12,plotOutput("testplot1", height = 1200)
                      ))),
      tabItem(tabName = "subtab2",
              fluidRow(column(12,plotOutput("testplot2", height = 1200)
              ))),
      tabItem(tabName = "subtab3",
              fluidRow(column(12,plotOutput("testplot3", height = 1200)
              ))),
      tabItem(tabName = "subtab4",
              fluidRow(column(12,plotOutput("testplot4", height = 1200)
    )))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

 output$testplot1 <- renderPlot({
 ggplot(data, aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point()+theme(plot.background = element_rect("green"))
   })

 output$testplot2 <- renderPlot({
 ggplot(data, aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point()+theme(plot.background = element_rect("red"))
   })

 output$testplot3 <- renderPlot({
 ggplot(data, aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point()+theme(plot.background = element_rect("blue"))
   })

 output$testplot4 <- renderPlot({
 ggplot(data, aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point()+theme(plot.background = element_rect("yellow"))
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```